# Formula with 4 conditions (IF)

Tags: worksheet-function

I have a hard time to figure out a formula with multiple conditions in Windows Office (Excel)

1. If A1<=5 or A1>=5       Then number should be "2"
2. If A1>=10 or A1>=-10    Then number should be "0"
3. If A1<10 but >5         Then bumber should be"2/(5-10)*(A1-10)"
4. If A1>-10 but <-5       Then number should be "2/((-5)-(-10))*((A)-(-10))

These are to find a score on a 3 slope chart

So for example

```
-6 or 6             should result at 1.6 
-9 or 9             should result at 0.4
-5 to 5             should result at 2
-10,-11,-12,-13...  should result at 0
10,11,12,13...      should result at 0
```

Hope it clarify my previous request, Thanks

Comment: What spreadsheet software are you using, on which OS?

Comment: That looks like three conditions to me where the first two you list are really if A is between -5 and 5 then the result should be 2.

Comment: What should the results be if A is between 5 and 10 or between -5 and -10?

Comment: If A1>5 but <10 Then number should be "2/(5-10)*(A1-10)" If A1>-10 but <-5 Then number should be "2/((-5)-(-10))*((A1)-(-10)) So for example -6 or 6 should result at 1.6 and -9 or 9 should result at 0.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using Windows with Office, the value is stored in cell A1, and you want to have the formula be written in cell B1.
To start, the first 2 IF's are used to find out if the value is between -5 and 5, as they have the same value.

So that would be written as: If A1 is between -5 and 5, then return 2. Given that Excel does not have a between function, you write it as follows:

```
=IF( AND(A1<=5;A1>=-5);2;...)
```

This means, if the condition is true, 2 is returned. Otherwise ...

Now the ... is what happens next. It can return a number, but you can also insert a formula there as well. So you can nest your IF's.

The IF for 3 is:

```
 IF(A1>=10;2/(5-10)*(A1-10);...)
```

This means, if the condition is true, the formula is executed. If not ...

The IF for 4 is:

```
IF(A1<=-10;2/((-5)-(-10))*(A1)-(010);...)
```

This means, of the condition is true, the formula is executed, if not ...

Now to combine it, you basically copy the IF from 4 into the ... from 3, what you get is copied in its entirely, and replaced in the formula for 1 and 2 where the ... is, which gives this:

```
=IF( AND(A1<=5;A1>=-5);2;IF(A1>=10;2/(5-10)*(A1-10);IF(A1<=-10;2/((-5)-(-10))*(A1)-(010);
...)))
```

Now of course, you still have one ... at the end. You have not specified what the formula should return in case they all are negative, which in your case is a value between -10 and -5 or 5 and 10. You could give the value that currently is in A1 by replacing the ... with A1. Your final formula would look like this:

```
=IF( AND(A1<=5;A1>=-5);2;IF(A1>=10;2/(5-10)*(A1-10);IF(A1<=-10;2/((-5)-(-10))*(A1)-(010);
A1)))
```

Here is that last formula written in a more clear fashion:

```
=IF
(AND(A1<=5;A1>=-5);2;
  IF
  (A1>=10;2/(5-10)*(A1-10);
    IF
    (A1<=-10;2/((-5)-(-10))*(A1)-(010);
      A1
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: I found the formula I was looking at, there it is.
=IF
  (AND($Q13<=$M13,$Q13>=$N13),$P13,
    IF
      (AND($Q13<$L13,$Q13>$K13),0,
       IF
        (AND($Q13<$N13,$Q13>$L13),$P13/($N13-$L13)*($Q13-$L13),
         IF
          (AND($Q13<$K13,$Q13>$M13),$P13/($M13-$K13)*($Q13-$K13),0))))

Comment: @David seems a lot like the formula I've written. If my answer helped you, feel free to accept it, so others know you no longer need help.